# Users with Restricted Read Permission can not view lists

Tags: list, development, permissions, administration, configuration

I have a Team Site inside my SharePoint 2013 enterprise server. and inside the site i created 4 lists, and i define the following :-

- Inside the first three lists (ListA , ListB, ListC) i define that UserA have "Restricted Read" permission on them (through a Group name "Site Visitors").
- Inside the fourth list (ListD) i stop the inheritance and define that for this list it have unique permission , and i gave UserA contribute permission (through the group named "Site Visitors").

now i was expecting the following result:-

- when UserA access the sub-site , he/she can view all lists, since he/she have restricted read on 3 of them and contribute on one of them.
- UserA will not be able to add/edit/delete items from the first 3 lists, while he should be able to the fourth list.

But the actual result was :-

- when UserA access the site he can only see the link for ListD (which he have contribute permission on ), as follow:-

[image]

- and if he tried to navigate to ListA,ListB,ListC by manully typing the URL he will get the following error:-

> Access Required Let us know why you need access to this site.

Here is how the page looks like for a user who have contribute permission on all the lists:-
[image]

//- Final Note:- The "Restricted Read" Permission level which i am using have the following permissions (those are the default permission):-

**List Permissions:-**

- View Items  -  View items in lists and documents in document libraries.
- Open Items  -  View the source of documents with server-side file handlers.

**Site Permissions:-**

- View Pages  - View pages in a Web site.
- Open  - Allows users to open a Web site, list, or folder in order to access
  items inside that container.

so can anyone adivce why restricted read users are not able to view the related lists , while restricted read should allow users to view/open list items and documents as per the permissions inside it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here (which is by design), is that the UserA does not have below permissions on the three lists:

```
View Application Pages
```

This permission is required to view all OOTB Forms, Views a list uses to show its contents and is not included in the "Restricted Read" permission level by default.

However, the UserA can still use the REST _api endpoints to see the list information as well as enumerate list items.

The documentation available [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understanding-permission-levels-in-SharePoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) is a little bit confusing but still exhaustive and worth reading to know various permissions and permission levels.

Comment: thanks for the info seems this is another confusing area in SP2013 !! so you mean in my case userA can not directly view the lists and their items from the UI, but he can view the lists and their items using the REST API ... so can you advice on these 2 points please ? 1) if i want userA to view the lists then what is the minimal permission level i need to grant to him , is this READ ? 2) second question if i want to prevent users from view the lists even using the REST API then what is the minimal permission level i need to grant them ?

Comment: 1) Yes, OOTB, Read is the permission level you need. You can also create a custom permission level where you can assign the Permissions "Restricted Read" has and "View Application Pages". That way you will have another minimal permission level that can view that list. 2. Don't assign any permissions at all.

Answer (score 1):

Restricted Read can view pages and items this doesn't mean that it can view lists.

You should add UserA to a group which as Read permission at site level.

Comment: but what does "View Items" permission mean exactly ?? , here is its description "View items in lists and documents in document libraries. " i think it mean the ability to view items inside lists ?? is this correct ?

Comment: If user don't have Read permission for list how he can view items inside that list. Confusing documentation 

Comment: so in this case what does this permission means exactly ""View items in lists and documents in document libraries." ? does it have any effect ?? second point is View have lower privilege compared to Read ??